# Error: Non-exhaustive patterns in Haskell

Tags: haskell, design-patterns

I have some code that deals with a list of lists (that represents a matrix). Each cell is an `N` or a `B`. I want to represent the matrix with the number of `N`s for each line. For example: `[[B,B,N],[N,N,N]]` is represented by `[1,3]`.

Here's my code:

```
data Case = B|N deriving (Show, Eq)
type Grille =[[Case]]

g0,g1 :: Grille
g0 = [[B,B,B,B,B,B,N],[B,B,N,B,N,B,B],[N,B,N,N,N,N,N],[B,B,B,N,N,B,N],[N,N,N,B,B,B,B],[B,B,B,N,N,B,N]]
g1 = [[B,B,B,B,B,B,B],[B,B,N,N,N,B,B],[B,B,N,N,N,N,N],[B,B,B,N,N,N,N],[N,N,N,B,B,B,B],[B,B,B,N,B,B,B]]

projH :: Grille -> [Int]
projH [[]] = []
projH (x:xg) = testCase(x) ++ projH(xg)

testCase :: [Case] -> [Int]dans une ligne
testCase [] = [0]
testCase (x:xs) 
    | x == N = [head(testCase(xs))+1]
    | otherwise = testCase(xs)
```

The problem is in the function `projH`, I'm obviously missing a pattern, but I do handle the case with `[[],...]` with the `testCase` function and the `[[]]` case. I don't know why it throws me this error:

```
*Main> projH g0
[1,2,6,3,3,3*** Exception: devoir.hs:(17,1)-(18,39): Non-exhaustive patterns in function projH
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
projH [] = []
```

instead of your

```
projH [[]] = []
```

As the case you wrote is already handled by the other statement by assigning `x = []` and `xg = []`