# Error: Non-exhaustive patterns in function Haskell

Tags: haskell

I did a thread for an error like this one, in it I explain my program. here's [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798284/error-non-exhaustive-patterns-in-haskell)

I'm going forward in my project and I have an another problem like that one. I did an other thread but if I just need to edit the first one just tell me.

I want to reverse my matrix. For example [[B,B,N],[N,B,B]] will become [[B,N],[B,B],[N,B]]. Here's my code:

```
    transpose :: Grille -> Grille
    transpose [] = []
    transpose g 
    | head(g) == [] = []
    | otherwise = [premierElem(g)] ++ transpose(supp g)

    supp :: Grille -> Grille
    supp [] = []
    supp (g:xg) = [tail(g)] ++ supp(xg)

    premierElem :: Grille -> [Case]
    premierElem [] = []
    premierElem (x:xg) = [head(x)] ++ premierElem(xg)
```

I got the exact same error and I tried like for the first one but that's not it.

EDIT: The exact error

`*Main> transpose g0
[[B,B,N,B,N,B],[B,B,B,B,N,B],[B,N,N,B,N,B],[B,B,N,N,B,N],[B,N,N,N,B,N],[B,B,N,B,B,B],[N,B,N,N,B,N],[*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list`

Comment: You shouldn't use the tail and head functions, you should use pattern matching. For example, in `premierElem g = [head(head(g))] ...` you know that `g` itself is a non-empty list because of the pattern `premierElem [] = ...` which precedes it, but you don't know that `head g` is a non-empty list. Same goes for `supp g = [tail(head(g))]  ...`

Comment: What do you mean by use the pattern matching? I tried to use the `(g:gx)` to minimise the number of `head()` and `tail()` but it won't work. Sorry if I don't understand I'm a beginner.

Comment: "I tried to use the (g:gx)" - this is correct, you are on the right track. If that code "doesn't work", include it in the question, as well as the error it gives you. Note that you will need to nest patterns, because you have a list of lists - for example `transpose ([]:xss) = ..; transpose ((x:xs):xss) = ...`

Comment: I did not mentioned, but I'll always have a matrix that is well formed. So I don't think that I need to cover these pattern, isn't it?

Comment: Please include your actual error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `transpose` function has a broken termination condition.  How does it know when to stop?  Try walking through the final step by hand...

In general, your case `transpose [] = []` will never occur, because your `supp` function never changes the number of lists in its argument.  A well-formed matrix will end up as `[[],[],[],...]`, which will not match `[]`.  The only thing that will stop it is an error like you received.

So, you need to check the remaining length of your nested (row?) vectors, and stop if it is zero.  There are many ways to approach this;  if it's not cheating, you could look at the implementation of `transpose` in the Prelude documents.

---

Also, re your comment above:  if you expect your input to be well-formed in some way, you should cover any excluded cases by complaining about the ill-formed input, such as reporting an `error`.

Comment: Indeed I did not notice this case. I can't use `transpose`(the prelude's one) I guess since it's all the point of the exercice. Is there a simple way to do it? I don't want to make an other function just for this... Seems like it's a bit too much. Is there a pattern to do this?

Comment: If all nested lists are supposed to be the same length, you can just check the first one.  This may more natural as a guard condition, than as a pattern match.

Comment: Oh yes thanks you. I did this (see the edit on my first post): 
`transpose :: Grille -> Grille
transpose [] = []
transpose g 
 | head(g) == [] = []
 | otherwise = [premierElem(g)] ++ transpose(supp g)`
But I wonder if there is a best way to do it? Nevertheless it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Fixing Your Code**

You should avoid using partial functions, such as tail and head, and instead make your own functions do (more) pattern matching.  For example:

```
premierElem g = [head(head(g))] ++ premierElem(tail(g))
```

Yuck!  If you want the first element of the first list in `g` then match on the pattern:

```
premierElem ((a:_):rest) = [a] ++ premierElem rest
```

This in and of itself is insufficient, you'll want to handle the case where the first list of the `Grille` is an empty list and at least give a useful error message if you can't use a reasonable default value:

```
premeirElem ([]:rest) = premeirElem rest
```

**Making Better Code**

Eventually you will become more comfortable in the language and learn to express what you want using higher level operations, which often means you'll be able to reuse functions already provided in `base` or other libraries.  In this case:

```
premeirElem :: [[a]] -> [a]
premeirElem = concatMap (take 1)
```

Which assumes you are OK with silently ignoring `[]`.  If that isn't your intent then other similarly concise solutions can work well, but we'd need clarity on the goal.

Comment: If an empty element is in fact erroneous, then it would be better to make it *impossible* with, e.g., `NonEmpty` than to paper over it with `concatMap` and risk incorrect answers.

Comment: Indeed this seems better that what I did. I'll edit my code and try to get used to this. But in fact that doesn't solve my error. I don't really know where does it come from since I covered (I think) all the cases with empty lists.

Comment: @pioupiou1211 You did not cover all cases.  For example, `premierElem (x:xg) = [head(x)] ++ premierElem(xg)` what if `x == []`?

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, but lacking a specification adding things like NonEmpty to the answer might be both incorrect and less clear.

Comment: @ThomasMDuBuisson, I was initially surprised to see what you wrote rather than `map head`, until I realized this was your way of filling in the hole in the specification. It's not clear to me that's the intent.